# Android service binding

Tags: android, service, bind

У меня есть один сервис и два `Activity`. Из одного `Activity` переходим на другой, и в методе `onStop` делаем `unbindService`. Tо-есть пришли во второй `Аctivity`, а сервис разрушился.

Когда второй `activity` вызывает `unbindservice`, создается новый сервис.

Как сделать так, чтобы `service` не разрушался ?

Comment: Приложите код где у вас в Activity вызывается bindService и unbindService (для обеих Activity). Очень смущает еще то что при unbindService второй Activity создается новый сервис...

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего вы присоединением к сервису его и стартуете, т.е. сервис запускается при вызове bindService:

```
bindService(intent, serviceConn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

флаг BIND_AUTO_CREATE запускает сервис при попытке присоединения к сервису, если он не запущен. В таком случае сервис будет работать до тех пор пока не вызван unbindService.

Вам надо напрямую стартовать сервис в первой Activity:

```
startService(intent);
```

чтобы при вызове unbindService при смене Activity (в вашем случае) сервис продолжал жить.

Остановить сервис можно вызовом:

```
stopService(intent);
```

Где стартовать и останавливать - решать вам, я бы стартовал на onCreate первой Activity, и останавливал бы его на onDestroy ее же.

Более подробно на эту тему на русском языке, с примерами, можно прочитать здесь: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html